# Make query sql that I add a new column with the results of the operation of my attributes

Tags: sql

My query would be

```
select obj, sum (att1), sum (att2)
from T1
group by obj
order by / * here I need to sort the obj by the results obtained between att1 / att2. * / -
```

Important the attribute of the table T1 obj is repeated but with different values ​​of att1 and att2 ---

what I want is shown in this table

```
Obj Att1. Att2. ResultOper 
AA. 20.    4.        5 
B.B. 14.    2.       7 
Cc. 10.     5.        2
```

Comment: I’m not understan your comment

Comment: First you say "I need to sort the obj by the results obtained between att1 / att2". But then your expected result has another order. Which order do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I need to sort the obj by the results obtained between att1 / att2"*:

```
select obj, sum (att1) s1, sum (att2) s2, sum (att1) / sum (att2) s3
from T1
group by obj
order by s3
```

Or, wrap it up in a derived table:

```
select obj, s1, s2,  s1 / s2 as s3
from
(
    select obj, sum(att1) s1, sum(att2) s2
    from T1
    group by obj
) dt
order by s3
```

Comment: The first option is what I want , but I want the result of s1 / s2 to be saved in a new column and ordered by this

Comment: Thanks for the answer